# LUA JSON - json.encode(json) with Backslash

Tags: json, lua

I'm a starter in lua, and when i try to encode a json table, with json.encode(json),
there are a lot of BACKSLASH () which are added in.
Someone can help me ? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you post your code, your expected results, and your actual results? See also [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.